# configure bonding/teaming on Redhat Linux 6.4

Tags: linux, bonding

[image: successful ping][image: ping output]I have configured a bonding/teaming for 2 Ethernet cards but the issue is when I hit the service network restart command I got a failed error regarding:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0 : line 2 IPADDR :192.168.10.25  command not find
```

and when I try `ping 192.168.10.25` it says `"connect :network is unreachable"`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have the `=` sign replaced by a `:` sign in your config file: `IPADDR:192.168.10.25` instead of `IPADDR=192.168.10.25`. Try to replace the `:` by a `=` and try to restart the network service.

Demonstration:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:1
DEVICE=eth1:1
HWADDR=08:00:27:1F:BE:7E
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR:192.168.56.102

ifup eth1:1
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:1: line 7: IPADDR:192.168.56.102: command not found
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:1: line 7: IPADDR:192.168.56.102: command not found
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:1: line 7: IPADDR:192.168.56.102: command not found
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:1: line 7: IPADDR:192.168.56.102: command not found
```

Changed `:` to `=`:

```
ifup eth1:1
Determining if ip address 192.168.56.102 is already in use for device eth1...

ifconfig eth1:1
eth1:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1F:BE:7E  
          inet addr:192.168.56.102  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. that was the issue. I have another issue, how can I make sure if the bonding is really working? I have tried to ping my host computer IP but the network was unreachable as well.

Comment: Can you ping the configured address from the host itself?

Comment: No I cant .. it says request time out .. please advise

Comment: I also turned off firewall on the VM .. with no connection to network too.. cant ping my host or VM both sides

Comment: Please update the question with the output of `ifconfig -a` on both sides.

Comment: I really cant as I'm installed the window system desktop.. just the terminal .. is there a specific lines you want to see so that I can write it myself here. Thanks

Comment: does not pinging mean that there is sth wrong of the bonding or it doesnt matter? Thanks

Comment: It does not necessarily to be an issue with the bond interface but you should start investigating by analyzing the interface properties, Therefore it is necessary to review the output of `ifconfig` to see if the interface is up, if the depending interfaces are up and so on. That you are unable to ping from the Windows host to the VM guest might also because of the network interface configuration (Bridge, NAT or Host-Only type of adapter). You might be able to grab and post a screenshot of the `ifconfig -a` information (and `ipconfig /all` information of the Windows host).

Comment: Done.. Please advse

Comment: So, I believe that you should be able to ping the address 192.168.10.25 from within the VM guest itself and I assume that the network connection is connected to the Windows network interface VMNet1. The VMNet1 interface is configured with an IP address in another subnet than the bond interface of the guest. When you try to ping the guest the Windows host does try to send the traffic to the gateway configured on the WLAN interface since it is not a local address. You will need to configure the VMNet1 interface with an address in the range of 192.168.10.xxx or add a dedicated route for cont..

Comment: cont. that specific subnet so the Windows host IP stack knows how to route traffic destined for 192.168.10.xxx. The first (adding a second IP address on VMNet1) is probably the easiest way to do.

Comment: Thanks for the advice .. it didnt work out with me .. I have updated the question with the output results .. Please advise.. many thanks in advance

Comment: I have changed bond interface to host subnet and apparently it worked out as shown in the images .. is that all I need to verify bonding/teaming? Thanks

Comment: I guess (when I review the edits of your question) that you changed the IP address on the wrong interface, WLAN interface instead of VMNet1.You should configure VMNet1 with an address in the same subnet range as configured on the bond interface. If I understand you correctly you have now configured the bonding interface with 192.168.1.100 and you are able to ping the address from the guest itself. That means that your bonding interface is up and running.